# Issue with Angular Universal Docker build

Tags: angular, docker, universal

When I'm trying to build my Docker file, I'm getting the below error

> ERROR in Cannot read property '0' of undefined
>
> > npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> >
> > > npm ERR! errno 1 npm
> > >
> > > > ERR! ssf@0.0.0 build:ssr: `ng build --prod && ng run ssf:server:production` npm ERR! Exit status 1

Please find below my Docker file

```
FROM node:10.16.3-slim AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package.json ./package-lock.json /app/
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
ENV NODE_OPTIONS --max-old-space-size=4096
RUN npm run build:ssr **(Error is coming at this line)**
COPY --from=build /app/package.json /app
COPY --from=build /app/dist /app/dist
EXPOSE 4000
ENV NODE_ENV production
CMD ["npm", "run", "serve:ssr"]
```

Also, this is the package.json snapshot

```
{
  "name": "ssf",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "dev:ssr": "ng run ssf:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build --prod && ng run ssf:server:production",
    "prerender": "ng run ssf:prerender"
    
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is still relevant.. but you can try replacing your dockerfile with the following:

```
### Stage: 1 ###
FROM node:14-alpine as Build
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package.json ./package-lock.json /app/
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
#This will create dist/ and dist-server/ folders in docker
RUN npm run build:ssr

### Stage: 2 ###
FROM node:14-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=Build /app/package.json /app
COPY --from=Build /app/dist /app/dist
COPY --from=Build /app/dist/server /app/dist-server

EXPOSE 4000

CMD ["npm", "run", "serve:ssr"]
```

I'm still testing this myself but I successfully run this container already.
Hope this will help you or others reading this.

Kind regards,
R